# How do I create new column in dataframe based on an existing column in Jupyter?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter

Let's say that i have a dataframe like:

```
    A   B
0   1   3
1   2   4
2   3   5
3   4   6
```

and i want a new column that is equal to A[i-1], and one equal to B[i-1], so:

```
    A   B   A1   B1
0   1   3   Nan  Nan
1   2   4   1    3
2   3   5   2    4
3   4   6   3    5
```

How do I do that?

Comment: Use df.shift()  https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC,

one idea is to pass the columns to a list and loop whilst assigning your col with `shift()`

```
cols = df.columns.tolist()
for col in cols:
    df[f'{col}1'] = df[col].shift(1)
print(df)

    A   B   A1  B1
0   1   3   NaN NaN
1   2   4   1.0 3.0
2   3   5   2.0 4.0
3   4   6   3.0 5.0
```

Comment: Can you explain how df[f'{col}1']  is working? I like it, I don't understand how.

Comment: @merit_2 it's an `f-string` which was added in a recent python version, it's the same as `.format` but _much_ faster and easier to read. it's basic string interpolation